# Sweave xtable too big

Tags: r, pdf, latex, sweave, xtable

Currently I have the following code:

```
<<xtable1, results=tex>>=
xtab<-xtable(Flag)
align( xtab ) <- "|c|c|c|c|c|"
print(xtab)
@
```

However, when I run this and it creates a pdf the table extends off of the page--like this.

How do I change it so it won't run off the page. I've tried the "tiny" but that makes it too small to read.

Comment: What do they each do? Do I use them after or before the <<>>= ?

Comment: OK, I  had a typo. I think the first is `\begin{landscape} <<...>>= .... @ \end{landscape}. While `\parbox` fits into your `xtable`. I'm pretty sure you put it in your column names. I don't have example code at the moment to check. You can find some examples on tex stackexhange and on the web.